# Multiple uses of self in same function

Tags: rust

I have an argument with the borrow checker. My problem is a little more complex, but for this case I am using a buffer like structure. My buffer has a function `safe_write_to_slot` that first retrieves the first empty element (returning a result that is either Ok(location) or an Err(error message)) and then writes a value to that retrieved location. The problem however is that when I assign the location that was retrieved to a value rust complains that I am reusing self again a few lines later. How do I first call a (self) function that returns a result, and then move on with self to do some action?

```
use std::result::Result;

struct Elems {
    pub elems : Vec<int>,
}

impl Elems {
    pub fn new() -> Elems {
        Elems{elems: vec![0,0,0,0,0,0]}
    }

    pub fn safe_write_to_slot(&mut self, elem : uint) -> Result<(), &str> {
        let loc = try!(self.get_slot());

        self.unsafe_write_to_slot(loc);

        Ok(())
    }

    pub fn get_slot(&self) -> Result<uint, &str>{
        let mut loc = -1i;

        for x in range(0, self.elems.len()) {
            if *self.elems.get(x) == 0 {
                loc = x as int;
            }
        }

        if loc != -1 { Ok(loc as uint) } else { Err("No free slots") }
    }

    fn unsafe_write_to_slot(&mut self, elem : uint) {
        self.elems[elem] = 1;
    }
}
```

The error that I get is:

```
   Compiling borrow v0.0.1 (file:///borrow)
main.rs:19:9: 19:13 error: cannot borrow `*self` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
main.rs:19         self.unsafe_write_to_slot(loc);
                   ^~~~
main.rs:17:24: 17:28 note: previous borrow of `*self` occurs here; the immutable borrow prevents subsequent moves or mutable borrows of `*self` until the borrow ends
main.rs:17         let loc = try!(self.get_slot());
                                  ^~~~
/main.rs:17:19: 17:41 note: expansion site
main.rs:22:6: 22:6 note: previous borrow ends here
main.rs:16     pub fn safe_write_to_slot(&mut self, elem : uint) -> Result<(), &str> {
/main.rs:22     }
               ^
main.rs:37:9: 37:29 error: cannot assign to immutable dereference (dereference is implicit, due to indexing)
main.rs:37         self.elems[elem] = 1;
                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
error: aborting due to 2 previous errors
Could not compile `borrow`.

To learn more, run the command again with --verbose.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lifetime inference is causing the issue here.

The `get_slot` method is interpreted as:

```
pub fn get_slot<'a>(&'a self) -> Result<uint, &'a str> {
```

The result is bound to the same lifetime as `self`, which causes `self` to remain frozen until the result is dropped. However, you don't want to link the lifetime of `self` to `&str`, because you're only returning string literals. By changing `&str` to `&'static str` in `get_slot` and `safe_write_to_slot`, you won't get the error anymore, because `self` will not be considered borrowed anymore when calling `unsafe_write_to_slot`.

Comment: Just for me to get things straight, what would happen if I would not only return string literals in the Result? Then I cannot use a static lifetime right?

Comment: `&'a str` means that you're returning a string slice that's valid at least as long as `self` is valid. This generally means that you're returning a slice of a string that is a member of `self`. In this case, the compiler disallows mutating `self` to prevent you from accidentally invalidating a string slice you returned earlier. However, if you're returning a string that's created in the function, then you'd have to use `String` instead.